# how to do row-major-order

Tags: python, grid

How to do a  row-major-order on x-axis in a 20x20 grid starting at (0,0). I have the grid done.

```
def __init__(self, xsize, ysize):
        self.maxX = xsize
        self.maxY = ysize
        self.thingList = []
        self.grid = []

        for row in range(self.maxY):
            row = []
            for col in range(self.maxX):
                row.append(None)
            self.grid.append(row)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "do a x-major-order"? I don't know of any operation or activity called an "x-major-order".

Comment: That still doesn't explain what you mean by doing one.

Answer (score 0):

People don't generally talk about row-major and column-major orderings in Python; Python hides these details from you pretty effectively.  Arrays in Python, which are different from lists, probably do give contiguous memory locations, but they're quite limited compared to lists, and lists probably don't.

Usually people care about these things so they can read a bunch of values into an n-dimensional array directly from disk; that isn't done in Python.  There are better ways, really, and Python pretty much makes you use them.

That said, you could fake an n-dimensional array using an array of floats or ints, and using multiplication and addition for array offsets.  This would give you control over row-major or column-major.

For most Python purposes, the row-majorness or column-majorness, are mostly a matter of how you *use* the datastructure, not how it's structured in virtual memory.